# Unable to push my Angular code into Github

Tags: git, github

I am new person for github,i try to upload angular project into github but only angular-cli code is created,i can not push my entire worked code,Thanks in advance.
After complete push operation it shows "untracked files: nothing added to commit but untracked files present" error

Comment: are you using the command line or the desktop client?

Comment: Hi,i am using command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do these steps

```
1. git add .
2. git commit -m "your commit name"
3. git push origin master
```

Comment: can you check what is remote url? you can use common "git remote -v"

Comment: I checked the url which i created as remote

Comment: did you add as a "origin"?

Comment: if "git add ." command does not add untracked files you also can use "git add --all" command

Comment: Changes not reflected